# How to change label color in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am problem in this javascript code, when I want to change color of label then it' not working but when I use return false after function in button it's work, This is button code 
onclick="myFunction(); return false">Save

but the same code return false is work but disabled button not open
onclick="myFunction();">Save
where I am wrong, Please Help, Thanks in Asvance

```
<?php
$isSaveDisabled = true;
$isCreateDisabled=false;
if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        echo 'Hello robin';
        $isCreateDisabled=false;
    }
if(isset($_POST['create']))
    {
        echo 'Byeeee robin';
        $isSaveDisabled = false;
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

         function myFunction()
        {
            document.getElementById("myH2").style.color = "#ff0000";

        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="container jumbotron">

        <form action="" method="post">

            <div class="btn-group-xs">
                <label for="name" id="myH2">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" >
            <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="save" <?php echo $isSaveDisabled?'disabled':''; ?>onclick="myFunction();">Save</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btn2" name="create" <?php echo $isCreateDisabled?'disabled':'';?>>Create</button>
            </div>


        </form>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using `type="submit` so page must be reloading and when you use `return false;` it cancels the default action of button in this form submit

Comment: Thanks friend but what i do in this code then my submit button work proper and javascript change label color work also proper

Comment: You can not have both..... The issue here is the fact you have a whiteboard. You write something on it. You than erase it when you hit the submit button. That means you need to write all the data again. So how can you run JavaScript? Well normally people will have the serverside apply the class when the page needs updated. Other option is to store state in the clientside localstorage and read it on page load, or people use Ajax instead of reloading the whole page.

Comment: OT: You should add an id attribute on the input with the same value as the value of label@for, that is `<input id="name">`. More explanations and examples in [Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls (H44)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44.html) (WCAG 2.0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change label color in javascript on submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106776/how-to-change-label-color-in-javascript-on-submit-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_color

If you just refer to the original code, you'll see that the button type is button, not submit.

So this will work:

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" ...and the rest as in your code
```

Comment: you are right friend and your given code work proper but i want to use type='submit' not button, because when i press create button user_id generate in text box , and i want when i press create button then both are work together like, generate user_id and label color change, but unfortunately only one function is running , what i do for this i am stuck on this .thanks in advance

Comment: @user3526020 you just need to run that function after the function that you think should run onsubmit. To run multiple functions, use onclick="myFunction(); mySecondFunction();"