# how to change label color in javascript on submit button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello Friend i have problem in my code,
In this code i want when i press save button then 'Hello PHP' print and label color of FIRST NAME change but it's not work, when I put submit in button type then it's shows 'Hello PHP' and label color not change and when I button in button type then label color change but not print 'hello PHP', I want both on save button Click , Please Help me to Stuck out from this code

This is my Code:

```
<?php
//php code 
$isSaveDisabled=true;
$isCreateDisabled=false;

if(isset($_POST['save_button']))
{
echo 'Hello PHP';
}

if(isset($_POST['create_button']))
{
$isSaveDisabled=false;
}
?>
// BootStrap Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My New PHP CODE</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootStrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myID").style.color = "#ff0000";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container jumbotron text-center">

    <form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname" id="myID">FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" >
             <label for="nlame">LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <br><br>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="submit" name="save_button" onclick="myFunction();" <?php echo $isSaveDisabled? 'disabled':'';?>>SAVE</button>
             <button type="submit" name="create_button" <?php echo $isCreateDisabled? 'disabled':''?> >CREATE</button>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label changes color after ckick on submit but page is refreshing immediately.
You can color the label by checking if button "save" was clicked :

```php
<?php

if($isSaveDisabled) {
  echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID").style.color = "#ff0000";</script>'
}
?>
```

Therefore your code will look:

```
<?php
//php code 
$isSaveDisabled=true;
$isCreateDisabled=false;

if(isset($_POST['save_button']))
{
echo 'Hello PHP';
}

if(isset($_POST['create_button']))
{
$isSaveDisabled=false;
}
?>
// BootStrap Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My New PHP CODE</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootStrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myID").style.color = "#ff0000";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container jumbotron text-center">

    <form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname" id="myID">FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" >
             <label for="nlame">LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <br><br>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="submit" name="save_button" onclick="myFunction();" <?php echo $isSaveDisabled? 'disabled':'';?>>SAVE</button>
             <button type="submit" name="create_button" <?php echo $isCreateDisabled? 'disabled':''?> >CREATE</button>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
  if($isSaveDisabled) {
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID").style.color = "#ff0000";</script>';
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother it's really very helpfull for me.